# Group by clause in case then end in HIveQL

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am having trouble in successfully running a query

```
select session from (select F_SESSION as session       
                     FROM T_TEMP GROUP BY F_SESSION  ) a ;
```

The above runs successfully. However, the below one fails

```
select session, count(total) from (select F_SESSION as session,                     
                   case when F_RECORDED_VALUE != 0 then F_RECORDED_VALUE end as total   FROM T_TEMP GROUP BY F_SESSION  ) a ;
```

The error is

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 4:30 Expression not in GROUP BY key '0'
```

Can someone point me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select session, count(total) from (select F_SESSION as session,                     
  case when F_RECORDED_VALUE != 0 then F_RECORDED_VALUE end as total FROM T_TEMP ) a
group by session;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do have group by F_SESSION in my sub query

Comment: I tried the updated answer.. got the same error. But i prefer to see this working in sub query as I will have multiple case when clause

Comment: It worked ... Thanks. I had put the group by inside but as you said it should be outside.